# Which software can download YouTube videos in MKV format at 360p?

Tags: download-manager, youtube

I tried IDM and 4k Video Downloader.

**IDM Experience**

While IDM gives the MKV option consistently at 480p, but it isn't consistent in offering MKV download option at 360p.

**4k Video Downloader**

While it does offer MKV option at 360p for all youtube videos, but it's download mechanism isn't very reliable. It often stops downloading the videos mid-way and one is forced to start the download for such videos all over again.

Aren't there other software alternatives to download youtube videos in MKV format at 360p?? (P.S.: I'm using Windows-7 32-bit version)

Comment: What's wrong with https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/ ?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Hello Nicolas! Thank you for your suggestion...I wasn't aware of this tool! I must say it's an extremely flexible tool! Could you help with one thing...While 4K Video Downloader can create an MKV for all URLs, but I am not sure how to create it using youtube-dl. I used this command: "youtube-dl.exe --list-formats youtube.com/watch?v=5SBG45jFrIA";. It did not give me any MKV file. But 4K Video Downloader gave me one right off the bat! Please help me create an MKV at 360p for this URL..!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Could you please write your comment as an answer instead, so that I can accept it as an answer? Right not, because of my low reputation, I can't even upvote your comment..

Comment: I would love to but I actually did not test MKV format at 360p myself. Please add your own answer detailing the command line parameters and other information, that will be useful for the next readers, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @NicolasRaoul for suggesting Youtube-Dl to me. I went ahead and after many hit & trials and attempts to make something out of the documentation, I came up with this command as the solution to download 360p MP4 DASH video with 48kHz Webm DASH audio:

```
youtube-dl.exe -f 134+249 --merge-output-format mkv --get-filename https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...
```

I hope to come back to this question later when I have the privileges to upvote your comment, @NicolasRaoul.

Answer (score 1):

To download YouTube video you have 2 ways:
- download with online downloader
- download with a special soft

If you prefer the first way, you will download the standart quality of the video - sometimes it is not 360. 
Thy the software and set your own qualities. 
The most popular downloaders according to Wikipedia:

Free Studio
BitComet
Free YouTube Downloader
DownThemAll!
FlashGet
Folx
Free Download Manager
DownloadStudio
Freemake Video Downloader
GetRight
Go!Zilla
JDownloader

Some programs content the adware, some of them not. All the programs is the professional soft.
You can also download the playlists 
https://www.dvdvideosoft.com/guides/how-to-download-youtube-playlist.htm

Try the different downloaders and choose what is the most simple for you)

Also you can use YouTubeRed, the official paid service of YouTube developers.